# How to insert a value from other table into the existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I am having two tables .

```
Table1 , Table2.
Table1 has name, age, salary.
Table2 has name,height, weight,Relevance,Weight_po etc.
```

. Both the tables has name as primary key.
Now I want to insert a two more new column in table 1 ie height, weight.
The values for height and weight has to fetch from Table2 where table1.name matches with table2.name.

Help me how to achieve this in postgres.

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select into statement and insert all data you want onto a NewTable with the structure you describe:

**EDIT:** Based on comment

```
Create table NewTable as
     SELECT Table1.name,age,salary,height,weight      
     INNER JOIN Table2 
     ON Table1.name=Table2.name
```

Comment: I am getting error ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "Table1"

Comment: Sorry for the typo.My table 2 has few more colums like name, height,weight,diameter,weight_po,relevance.But I need only height and weight

Comment: `select .. into .. from ..` is a deprecated non-standard syntax. It's better to use `create table as select ...` instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you created height and weight columns in Table 1?

This will help to populate the values:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 
SET height= t2.height,weight=t2.weight 
FROM Table2 t2 
WHERE t1.name= t2.name
```

Tell me how it goes